# Add assumptions to Solve command

Tags: equation-solving, conditional

I want Mathematica to solve the following by assuming the part within the `Log` function, which is `((P - T) (L - P0))/((L - P) (P0 - T))`, to be positive and give a result that is not a conditional expression. How do I add assumptions to the `Solve` command?

```
Clear[k, P, t, T, L, P0]
Solve[L/(L - T) (Log[((P - T) (L - P0))/((L - P) (P0 - T))]) == k*t,
P]
```

Any suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE @MathHelpNeeded! I suggest: 1) You take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now! 2) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)! 3) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise.

Comment: @MathHelpNeeded I converted my previous comment to your question into an answer. If you find that it useful, I would appreciate it if you would officially accept it. Thanks!

Answer (score 13):

The `ConditionalExpression` output by `Solve` in your case does not really depend on the whole argument of the `Log` function in your original equation, but only on the following expression:

```
-π < Im[(k t (L - T))/L] ≤ π
```

If it is possible in your case to make assumptions on the values of those parameters, you could then try to `Simplify` the output of `Solve` using the `Assuming` function.

For instance, if your parameters are real numbers, and `L` is positive, you could write:

```
Assuming[
  { {k, t, L, T, P} \[Element] Reals, L > 0},
  Simplify[
    Solve[L/(L - T) (Log[((P - T) (L - P0))/((L - P) (P0 - T))]) == k*t, P]
  ]
]
```

The result of that last command no longer depends on a `ConditionalExpression`.