# Correctly restricting domain of parameters within Solve

Tags: equation-solving, assumptions

I have seen a few posts about this (such as [this one](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/81004/add-assumptions-to-solve-command)), but none solved my problem.
As a silly example, suppose I want to solve `(1-x)^n = 0`, knowing that n > 1. I tried doing,

```
Assuming[n > 1, Solve[(1 - x)^n == 0, x]]
```

But, Mathematica goes a bit crazy and gives,

```
{x -> 1 - 0^(1/n)}
```

with a warning message. Now, the answer is technically correct I guess, but I would really just like to see `x -> 1` of course.
Note that Mathematica probably ignores the assumption, because, if I assume `n < -1`, then I get the same output anyway, although there really is no solution. Is there a way to make this work as expected?

Comment: How about `Solve[(1 - x)^n == 0 && n > 1, x]` ?

Comment: Ok, that works, although I fail to see what was wrong with my attempt?
Thanks anyway.

Comment: `Solve[]` does not make use of `$Assumptions`, so `Assuming[..]` is effectively a no-op.

Comment: You could also add a domain specification to Solve: `Solve[(1-x)^n == 0, x, Reals]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`Solve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Solve.html) does not take the option [`Assumptions`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assumptions.html), consequently the [`Assuming`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Assuming.html) construct has no affect on it. The constraint (`n > 1`) should be included within `Solve` and as an assumption when simplifying.

```
Solve[{(1 - x)^n == 0, n > 1}, x]

(* {{x -> ConditionalExpression[1, n > 1]}} *)
```

[`Simplify`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Simplify.html) accepts `Assumptions` so you can simplify the output of `Solve` using either

```
Simplify[
 Solve[{(1 - x)^n == 0, n > 1}, x],
 Assumptions -> n > 1]

(* {{x -> 1}} *)
```

or

```
Simplify[Solve[{(1 - x)^n == 0, n > 1}, x], n > 1]

(* {{x -> 1}} *)
```

or

```
Assuming[n > 1, Solve[{(1 - x)^n == 0, n > 1}, x] // Simplify]

(* {{x -> 1}} *)
```

Answer (score 1):

As suggested by Nasser, just try,

```
Solve[(1-x)^n && n > 1,x]
```

If you want to get rid of the Conditional expression which ensues, just apply `Normal` to the above expression.

Comment: Even $n>0$ works in the above.